# Notifying multiple cursor loaders in one go

Tags: android, asynctaskloader

I have an app with three activities A, B, C each showing list view from a DB using asynctaskloader.

I maintain the reference of the loader for the latest activity in a broadcast receiver. When there is a data change I call `onContentChanged` on the corresponding loader to update the `listView` but if I am in activty `B` or `C` the listview in the parent activity is not getting updated.

I know I can maintain a reference for each loader separately and call `onContent` on each of them but was curious if all loaders can be updated in one shot? Didn't see anything relevant in the loaderManager apis.

Comment: Use ContentResolver#notifyChange()

Comment: hi @pskink my db is not modeled as a content provider..